# java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...keystore.jks (No such file or directory) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ssl, jmx

First off, I want to deactivate JMX-functionality in my workspace.

I just deactivated all (I hope) references to JMX in my project but when starting the tomcat, I get this failure:

```
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Volumes/SDE_Mac/apache-tomcat-7.0.40/conf/keystore.jks (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)"
```

Additionally, he still tries to open the tomcat at the port I wanted to use with JMX. 
But in our configuration "useJmxMailingService" is set to `false`.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign `keystore` path on `server.xml` of tomcat.

```
<Connector 
     port="8443" maxThreads="200"
     scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
     keystoreFile="${path of key stokre}/keystore.jks" /*Put the keystoer path*/
     keystorePass="changeit"
     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: Excuse me, I just realised, that my question wasn't easy to read. I want to deactivate JMX. So I will try your solution the other way around.

Comment: Removing the connector removed the failure. Thank you for that. But when starting, he still tries to reach the wrong port.

Comment: Removing security constraints from the web.xml solved the rest of the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Wutzefreck please tell your approach clearly. I am facing similiar but with ubuntu tomcat path